# A list of properties for an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

If I want to use javascript to change a property of something on a page I find it difficult to find the correct name to use.

For example if I have a button and I want to change the background colour I can use .style.background which I could find with a quick search on the net BUT what I can't seem to find is a comprehensive list of all the properties associated with  that I could change.

Are there lists like this? Why cant I find them?

Comment: Because your Google-fu is broken? :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) to find the documentation for each DOM object type.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLFormElement), for example, is a page describing the DOM interface for the `form` element, complete with properties and methods.

If you're going to use a console, I'd recommend logging the objects directly for an interactive view, instead of just logging a list of property names:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

console.log(div);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var div = document.createElement('div')​;

​for (prop in div)​ {
    console.log(prop);
}​
```

This will list ALL the properties available on the div element in that particular browser.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KWXwZ/)

`element.style.background` will probably not be listed, as that is a style, not a property, but you can get all the styles by doing:.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

console.log(div.style);
```

Comment: Or you could just log the object itself, if you're using a console anyway.

Comment: @Asad - It's an element, so it will just print `<div></div>` in the console.

Comment: @adeneo In most consoles, you can examine DOM objects in a separate panel. In Firebug for example, I can right click the entry and select `Inspect in DOM Panel` to see all its properties in an expandable view.

Comment: Yeah, it was the same time on both. Also, `style.background` is listed. I'd never looked at the list before, there's a few more than I thought.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - It's probably listed in the styles, I meant it's not listed among the properties, and added the styles to the answer, as that seemed to be what the OP was after ??